# Android app latitude and longitude values are coming even though no network or gps

Tags: java, android, latitude-longitude

I have written an android app to find latitude and longitude.
latitude and longitude values are coming even though no network or gps.
I think previous latitude and longitude values are stored in cache.
How to clear cache values.

Answer (score 2):

This will work on Samsung phones. :

```
private void deleteGpsData(){
        /* Cold start */
        Bundle extra = new Bundle();
      if(mStartMode == GPS_COLD_START){
          extra.putBoolean("ephemeris", true);
          extra.putBoolean("position", true);
          extra.putBoolean("time", true);
          extra.putBoolean("iono", true);
          extra.putBoolean("utc", true);
          extra.putBoolean("health", true);
          extra.putBoolean("svdir", true);
          extra.putBoolean("svsteer", true);
          extra.putBoolean("sadata", true);
          extra.putBoolean("rti", true);
          extra.putBoolean("celldb-info", true);
      }
      else if(mStartMode == GPS_WARM_START)
      {
          extra.putBoolean("ephemeris", true);
          extra.putBoolean("time", true);
      }

        locationMgr.sendExtraCommand(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, "delete_aiding_data", extra);
    }
```

Now if you call `requestLocationUpdates()` the GPS cache will be empty.

Comment: thanks... am using wifi and network provider. how to clear wifi data in cache

Comment: You will have to root your phone for that, depending on the [implementation](http://gitorious.org/android-eeepc/base/blobs/56fe6be0c3e1eaa7d5d1ba96910008c504a6c362/services/java/com/android/server/LocationManagerService.java), the cache is stored at `/data/location/<provider_name>/`

Comment: how to declare mStartMode and GPS_COLD_START

Comment: mStartMode ,GPS_COLD_START  how to define mStartMode == GPS_COLD_START

Comment: You can declare it as an `public static final int`